# Laplace Transform Example: $\mathcal{L}(e^{it}) = \left[ \frac{e^{(i - s)t}}{i - s} \right]_0^\infty = \frac{1}{s - i}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

My textbook on Laplace transforms gives the following example:

> $$\begin{align} \mathcal{L}(e^{it}) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} e^{it} \ dt \\ &= \int_0^\infty e^{t(i - s)} \ dt \\ &= \left[ \dfrac{e^{(i - s)t}}{i - s} \right]_0^\infty \\ &= \dfrac{1}{s - i} \\ &= \dfrac{s}{s^2 + 1} + i\dfrac{1}{s^2 + 1} \end{align}$$

How did the author get from $\left[ \dfrac{e^{(i - s)t}}{i - s} \right]_0^\infty$ to $\dfrac{1}{s - i}$? We actually get $\left[ \dfrac{e^{(i - s)t}}{i - s} \right]_0^\infty = \dfrac{e^{(i - s)\infty}}{i - s} - \dfrac{1}{s - i}$, and I don't see how it's valid to just discard $\dfrac{e^{(i - s)\infty}}{i - s}$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that De Moivre's formula tells you that $e^{it}$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ is bounded because $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ are bounded.

$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal{L(e^{it})}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(i-s)t}\mathrm dt\\&=\left[\dfrac{e^{(i-s)t}}{i-s}\right]_{0}^{\infty}\\&=\underbrace{\lim_{t\to \infty}\dfrac{e^{it}}{e^{st}(i-s)}}_{\to 0}-\dfrac{1}{i-s}\\&\to \dfrac{1}{s-i}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: But it’s not clear why that should be the case, since what you actually have is an indeterminate form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$. It seems to me like some deeper level of justification is required here by using concepts from complex analysis?

Comment: De Moivre's formula tells you that $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ and sine and cosine are bounded for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ so clearly $e^{st}$ outspeeds $e^{it}$ in growth as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: yes, you are right. This explains it very well. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: You're welcome @ThePointer Cheers :))

Comment: De Moivre's theorem is a more powerful theorem than warranted here. All that is needed is that for $z\in\mathbb C$, $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $|z|=r$. Since $|z|=1$, $t\mapsto it$ is uniformly bounded in $t$, in particular $|e^{ix}|= \mathsf 1_{\{1\in\mathbb R\}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$Note that for any real $t$ and complex $s$, we have $$\left|e^{(i-s)t}\right| = e^{\Re((i-s)t)} = e^{-at},$$ where $a=\Re(s)$. (Recall in general that $\left|e^z\right| = e^{\Re(z)}$ for any complex $z$.) So you can see that if $a=\Re(s) > 0$, we have $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\left|e^{(i-s)t}\right|  = 0$, and so $$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{(i-s)t}}{i-s}=0.$$

Comment: This is interesting. Where is the fact that $\left|e^z\right| = e^{\Re(z)}$ from?

Comment: This can be found by writing $z=x+iy $ where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$ respectively. Then $e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^x e^{iy}$. Hence $$\begin{align}\left|e^z\right| &= \left|e^x\right|\left|e^{iy}\right| \\ &= e^x \cdot 1 \\ &= e^x \\ &= e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)}.\end{align}$$